# ios app rejected because of ipv6 incompatibility after making all suggestion

Tags: ios, iphone

My app has been rejected 4 times because of ipv6 incompatibility.But I have already made changes in my app to support ipv6.

1) I have used latest AFNetworking class

2) checking reachability with hostname method

3) Even made our server fully ipv6 supported.

Then also app gets rejected with following reason:

We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPhone running iOS 10.2.1 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.

Specifically, launching your app, resolves to a black screen.

Comment: It may not be related to IPV 6 , They have mentioned environment on which they tested, OS and Network type, issue could be something else ( launching your app, resolves to a black screen)

Comment: But they have provided info as I put in question,nothing else.Any solution?

Comment: Just change the build number and resubmit the same version :) Also, tell us if your app uses iCloud or App Groups.

Comment: i did it 4 times already.No app doesn't use iCloud or App Groups but it uses facebook ads

Comment: Apple include the IPV6 warning when they reject an app, whether or not that was the cause. Have you had a rejection that was definitely caused by an IPv6 bug? Basically, your app is crashing - you need to figure out why and fix that.

Comment: yes they have provided that only reason,no other reason is provided

Comment: @Swift_Guru are you using HTTPS ?

Comment: yes I am using it

Comment: @Swift_Guru : are your development and production web services different ? or same ?

Answer (score 0):

I already have this issue with Apple guys, even with an IPV6 compatible app. Make sure the server you are calling is IPV6 compliant. You can use for example [This site](http://ipv6-test.com/validate.php) to test that the WS/server/machine you want to reach can "talk" with this protocol.

If it's the case, you can easily explain to Apple that the app is IPV6 compatible, by using URLSession only (for example), but it's the distant server which is not.

Got the problem twice, twice explain as above: succeed.

EDIT: Be sure by using AFNetworking, you are using 3.x version, and not 2.x (not IPV-6 compatible because using NSURLConnection instead of NSURLSession)

Comment: our server is ipv6 compatible and i have uploaded my app 4 times

Comment: You can test your app with IPV-6 protocol using a shared connection on your mac + enable NAT64 . See [This link - Apple Dev Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4971).

Comment: I already said we have tested our app and it is ipv6 compatible

Comment: There is not much to said dude. If Apple said "IPV6 problem", you have a IPV6 problem. Even if you "already" test it, retest your app, and retest the backend part with your sysadmin in IPV6 request mode. Nowadays it's a common mistake to believe backend is IPV6 compliant, when not (for example Amazon Web Service - AWS - is NOT IPV-6 compliant)

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same issue. Mine was also rejected due to IPV6. Check below two things for your application:

1) Make sure you API link which you used in your application, doesn't have any ip address. If you calling API using IPAddress then your application will rejected.

2) Do testing your application using IPV6 network thorugh your system. Here is the link.

If your application is fullfill both testcase, then don't do any thing, just right comment in iTuneConnect and told them that my application is running in IPV6 network. Can you please guide to find my issue? If possible then can I have a call with your representative?

**So they ask your contact detail and give you call and your issue will resvoled. I have wasted around 20 days to solved this issue. But apple representative told that this is them internal issue.**

So my humble advice to contact Apple representative as soon as possible and your issue will resolve without doing anything.